# BizTalk 2013 R2 - Decision Shape not following correct logic path

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Issue with an old Biz app (not designed or developed by myself).

Its orchestration receives a particular message, which is then fed into a Decision shape. If the below logic applies (as directly copy/pasted from the shapes first branch expression), it should go that route.

```
msg_inputCanonical.CRUD == "D" && msg_inputCanonical.DbTable == "Staff"
```

I can see it terminating however (by using the Orchestration Debugger) as it follows the Else branch and eventually hits a terminate shape.

I've checked the msg_inputCanonical to confirm the values being passed through (as below extracted from the Tracked Message part), and can see it matches the string condition in accordance with its mapping - CRUD = ChOp;

```
<DbTable>Staff</DbTable>
<ChOp>D</ChOp>
```

There's nothing else that I can see that's influencing this re-route, so can anyone think of any quirks that might be causing it?

*Note: I've amended the WCF-SQL Stored Procedure that generates the msg_inputCanonical as prior to this it wasn't trimming any of the CRUD/DbTable values and had been leaving deadspace in.
There is also a map that uses ltrim/rtrim functoids on the `ChOp` property, but again - can't see what harm trimming an already trim'd field would do.*

I have also tried replicating the logic in a dev environment, and it works as expected going down the correct branch when I'm passing the message through.

Comment: I remember from an earlier question you don't have a dev/test environment, so maybe you can create a simple FILE receive and send port that uses the same mapping, just to be sure the output is really what you expect. Also, I hope you're checking the files in a text editor, since many XML viewers strip any white-space as well.

Comment: * or just a send port that subscribes to the same message

Comment: Hi Ruud, since my prior post I've managed to get a VM spun up and have got a dev environment of Biz working, so I'm now able to break and experiment with great abundance :)
I've tested this approahc already (should've clarified in my post, apologies) and can't replicate the issue (it works fine in my mockup build).
I've also santisied the message in Notepad+ with the relevant char views on to spot deadspace/chars and it looks fine.

Comment: You've shown us part of the  input message, can you also double check those fields in the output message from the map and show them here? As that is what the logic is executing on.

Comment: Sure, I've stripped out some fields that aren't relevant but as you can see, the CRUD (which equates to the ChOp in the transformation) is D and doesn't contain any deadspace, and the dbTable is StaffTable as per the logic:

<ns0:Records xmlns:ns0="http://SALTO.InputCanonical">
 <CRUD>D</CRUD>
 <DbTable>Staff</DbTable>
</ns0:Records>